# Reference Issue (error BC30007: Reference required to assembly) while building VS2010 Project using MSBUILD Plugin of Jenkins

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild, jenkins

I am using Jenkins MSBUILD plugin to build my VS2010 project. When i build the job it gives me 
error "BC30007: Reference required to assembly 'System.Data.DataSetExtensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' containing the base class 'System.Data.TypedTableBase`1'. Add one to your project. [C:\BitNami\jenkins-1.538-1\apps\jenkins\jenkins_home\workspace\ProjectName]" while same project when i build using VS2010 IDE there is no issue in it. how to solve this error ??

Answer (score 0):

Found a possible answer to this problem. At least it solved the problem for me.
Add this to the end of your project file before the  end tag:

`<Target Name="AfterResolveReferences">
    <!-- Redefine referencepath to add dependencies-->
    <ItemGroup>
        <ReferencePath Include="@(ReferenceDependencyPaths)"></ReferencePath>
    </ItemGroup>
</Target>`

Source: http://www.nsilverbullet.net/2012/02/17/automatically-resolving-secondary-assembly-references-with-msbuild-and-tfs-build/